# Modify pointer to std::string inside C++ class

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I just started to learn `C++` and encountered an inconsistency using `gnu` compiler on the one hand and using `Visual C++` and `Intel compiler` on the other hand. Following example defines a class `Person` with a pointer to a std::string `Name`. Within method `Person::set` the string is assigned by value. I'm sure the better way would be to use a pointer, but that's not the question here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Person
{
   std::string *Name;
public:
   Person(std::string *n);  //Constructor
   void print();
   void set(std::string n);
};

Person::Person(std::string *n) : Name(n) //Implementation of Constructor
{
}

// This method prints data of person
void Person::print()
{
    std::cout << *Name << std::endl;
}


void Person::set(std::string n)
{
    Name = &n;
}

int main()
{
    std::string n("Me");
    std::string n2("You");
    Person Who(&n);

    Who.print();
    Who.set(n2);
    Who.print();


    return 0;
}
```

The gnu compiler gives following result as I would have expected:

```
Me
You
```

But the `Visual C++` and `Intel` compilers result in an undefined behviour. I guess the problem is the life time of the copied variable `n` in `Person::set`. Why is it still available after finishing `Person::set` using `gnu` compiler and not available using `Visual C++` and `Intel` compilers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Set` method is setting you up undefined behaviour because you are taking the address of a local variable, and then use it in another scope:

```
void Person::set(std::string n)
{
    Name = &n; // n is a local variable
}
```

Any attempt to de-reference `Name` outside of `Person::set`, as you do in `Person::print()`, is *undefined behaviour*.

The behaviour of all the compilers you tried is compatible with undefined behaviour, because everything is.

Comment: If there is anything incorrect with this answer I would like to know. If there is any other good reason for the down-vote, it would be useful to know too so I can consider fixing it if appropriate.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: `n` is not a temporary. It's a local variable. It has an address and there's nothing undefined about storing that address.

Comment: @KerrekSB Good point, thanks. I re-phrased the answer. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 3):

That code is completely broken and unusable. Inside `Person::set`, `n` is a local variable, so its address `&n` is meaningless outside that function. Storing it is pointless, and using to it later is undefined behaviour.

---

Here's a correct way to write your class in modern C++:

```
class Person
{
   std::string Name;

public:
   explicit Person(std::string n) : Name(std::move(n)) { }

   void set(std::string n) { Name = std::move(n); }

   void print() const { std::cout << Name << '\n'; }
};
```

Comment: Are the move's really necessary? Won't an optimizing compiler do at least something similar without them?

Comment: @rubenvb: I don't think anything allows a compiler to ignore the rules of overload resolution, non?

Answer (score 1):

The "better way" isn't *always* to use a pointer in C-like languages.  Touché.

Even if you correctly passed a pointer to set:

```
void Person::set(std::string* n)
{
    Name = n; // Correctly saves
}
```

You have no idea when `n` will be deallocated, since it is stored *outside* the `Person class`. A better way to do this would be to *keep a copy* of `Name` inside the `Person` class, and pass in new strings by reference:

```
class Person
{
   std::string Name;
public:
   Person(const std::string &n);  //Constructor
   void print();
   void set(const std::string &n);
};

Person::Person(const std::string &n) : Name(n) //Implementation of Constructor
{
}

void Person::set(const std::string &n)
{
    Name = n; // Person class keeps its own copy of n
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was aware that it is stored outside the class. So your answer doesn't really answer my question. I just wanted to know how long n lives inside set method.